# Optimize hostapd for highest range

Tags: wifi, hostapd

I have an Alfa Wifi dongle. This dongle should have a sensitivity of -100 dbi at 1 MBit speed.

- Is it enough to set `hw_mode` to "a" to get highest range?
- Are there other settings which have to get changed?

My config:

```
###############################
# Basic Config
###############################
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211

###############################
# DRAFT-N
###############################
#ieee80211n=1
#ht_capab=[HT40-][SHORT-GI-20][SHORT-GI-40]
#wmm_enabled=1
channel=8

##########################
# Local configuration...
##########################
ssid=bar
hw_mode=b
#hw_mode=g
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=foo
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'highest range'? Many drivers have no sensitivity settings. Try `iwconfig  wlan0 sens`.

Comment: I mean the highest range I get with the lowest data transfer rate, in theory. The higher the data rate the less sensitive the sensor becomes. For my purposes I am fine to have even 1 MB/s. I just need range.

Comment: I see, in other words it's the distance. I'd say this setting has become obsolete through frequency hopping and other features that are managed by hardware. Anyways, you need to tune other settings regarding the hardware capabilities. `iw phy` is a good starting point.

Comment: I am not sure, whether frequency hopping or reducing the data rate will not cause lags for a short time when applied. I guess it is so and I don't want to have them. I just want a steady connection over a high distance.

Comment: The algorithm checks continuously for the line quality and selects the best connection, but you still can clamp it to the lowest throughput. High sensitivity and low power sender results in high noise. What you can do is to increase txpower  to (allowed) maximum, purchase good (directional) areal. [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=wifi+directional+areal+wide+range&btnG=Search#q=wifi+directional+areal+%22long+range%22)